# MediatR unable to resolve this issue

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, mediatr

Project is in .NET 6 WebAPI C#

The error says and I can't figure out why

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'No service for type 'MediatR.IRequestHandler`2[CFR.Server.Application.Reporting.Queries.GetAllReportingQuery,CFR.Blazor.Shared.AllReports]' has been registered.'

Full Stack Trace

```
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService(IServiceProvider provider, Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService[T](IServiceProvider provider)
   at MediatR.Wrappers.RequestHandlerWrapperImpl`2.<>c__DisplayClass1_0.<Handle>g__Handler|0()
   at MediatR.Wrappers.RequestHandlerWrapperImpl`2.Handle(IRequest`1 request, IServiceProvider serviceProvider, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at MediatR.Mediator.Send[TResponse](IRequest`1 request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at CFR.Server.Controllers.ReportingController.GetAll() in ReportingController.cs:line 29
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor.AwaitableObjectResultExecutor.<Execute>d__0.MoveNext()
```

Controller

```
namespace CFR.Server.Controllers
{
    [ApiController]
    [Authorize]
    [Route("[controller]")]
    public class ReportingController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly IMediator _mediator;

        public ReportingController(IMediator mediator)
        {
            _mediator = mediator;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Api endpoint to get all report for issue page
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>AllReports</returns>
        [HttpGet]
        public Task<AllReports> GetAll() => _mediator.Send(new GetAllReportingQuery() { }); // CRASHES HERE
    }
}
```

Startup

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddCors(options => options.AddPolicy("AppCORSPolicy", p => p.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader()));
            services.AddSingleton(new ConnectionString
            {
                Value = Configuration.GetConnectionString("Development")
            });


            services.AddControllersWithViews();
            services.AddRazorPages();
            services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
            services.ConfigureAuth(Configuration);
            services.AddInfrastructure();
            services.AddSwaggerGen();
            services.AddResponseCompression();
            services.AddMediatR(m => m.RegisterServicesFromAssembly(typeof(Program).Assembly));

            services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
            {
                c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "API", Version = "v2" });
                c.AddSecurityDefinition("Bearer", new OpenApiSecurityScheme()
                {
                    Description = "JWT Authorization header using the Bearer scheme. Example: \"Bearer {token}\"",
                    Name = "Authorization",
                    In = ParameterLocation.Header,
                    Type = SecuritySchemeType.ApiKey,
                });
                c.AddSecurityRequirement(new OpenApiSecurityRequirement{
                    {
                        new OpenApiSecurityScheme
                        {
                            Reference = new OpenApiReference
                            {
                                Type = ReferenceType.SecurityScheme,
                                Id = "Bearer"
                            },
                            Scheme = "oauth2",
                            Name = "Bearer",
                            In = ParameterLocation.Header,
                        },
                        new List<string>()
                    }
                });
            });
        }
```

GetAllReportingQuery file

```
namespace CFR.Server.Application.Reporting.Queries
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Query for [Get] Reporting
    /// </summary>
    public class GetAllReportingQuery : IRequest<AllReports>
    {
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Handler for GetAllReportingQuery
    /// </summary>
    public class GetAllReportingQueryHandler : IRequestHandler<GetAllReportingQuery, AllReports>
    {
        private readonly IViewRepository _repository;

        public GetAllReportingQueryHandler(IViewRepository repository)
        {
            _repository = repository;
        }

        public async Task<AllReports> Handle(GetAllReportingQuery request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            // Get each of reporting item reporting results in order
            var booksIssuedLocations = await _repository.All<BooksIssuedLocation>();
            var booksMonthlySummaries = await _repository.All<BooksMonthlySummary>();
            var inventoryByLocations = await _repository.All<InventoryByLocation>();
            var monthlyComparisonPrior = await _repository.All<MonthlyComparisonPrior>();
            var monthlyComparison = await _repository.All<MonthlyComparison>();
            var booksIssuedVsClosed = await _repository.Single<BooksIssuedVsClosed>();
            var manualVsAutoCloseCount = await _repository.Single<ManualVsAutoCloseCount>();
            var errorsToCorrectCount = await _repository.Single<ErrorsToCorrectCount>();
            var boxInTransitCount = await _repository.Single<BoxInTransitCount>();
            var statusCodeDifferences = await _repository.Single<StatusCodeDifferences>();
            var conductorNfCount = await _repository.Single<ConductorNfCount>();
            var countConductorNoRemit = await _repository.Single<CountConductorNoRemit>();

            var all = new AllReports
            {
                BooksIssuedLocations = booksIssuedLocations,
                BooksIssuedVsClosed = booksIssuedVsClosed,
                BooksMonthlySummaries = booksMonthlySummaries,
                InventoryByLocations = inventoryByLocations,
                // MonthByMonthTotals = await _repository.All<MonthByMonthTotals>(),
                ManualVsAutoCloseCount = manualVsAutoCloseCount,
                ErrorsToCorrectCount = errorsToCorrectCount,
                BoxInTransitCount = boxInTransitCount,
                StatusCodeDifferences = statusCodeDifferences,
                ConductorNfCount = conductorNfCount,
                CountConductorNoRemit = countConductorNoRemit,
                MonthlyComparisonPrior = monthlyComparisonPrior,
                MonthlyComparison = monthlyComparison
            };


            return all;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is IViewRepository registered correctly?

Comment: Is the query handler in the same assembly as `Program`?

Comment: @NeilW how can I confirm this? I took over a project that was written by someone else.

Comment: @ProgrammingLlama how do I confirm this? I am taking over a project from someone else. I can share Program.cs if you think it will help

Comment: Well, if you have two projects, and one project is (for example) a "class library", and the other is an ASP.NET Core web application, then you have two assemblies. Is that the case? Is the handler in a different project/assembly?

Answer (score -2):

```
services.AddMediatR(m => m.RegisterServicesFromAssembly(typeof(Program).Assembly));
services.AddTransient<IRequestHandler<GetAllReportingQuery, AllReports>, GetAllReportingQueryHandler>();
services.AddTransient<IRequestHandler<SaveAssigmentCommand, AssignBookForTrainingPageResult>, SaveAssigmentCommandHandler>();
services.AddTransient<IRequestHandler<SaveNotesCommand, bool>, SaveNotesCommandHandler>();
services.AddTransient<IRequestHandler<PrintReceiptCommand, BookReceiptInfo>, PrintReceiptCommandHandler>();
services.AddTransient<IRequestHandler<AssignBookLoadCommand, AssignBookForTrainingPageResult>, AssignBookLoadCommandHandler>();
services.AddTransient<IRequestHandler<GetBookIssuedReportQuery, IEnumerable<BookIssuedReport>>, GetBookIssuedReportQueryHandler>();
services.AddTransient<IRequestHandler<GetBookIssuedReportPdfQuery, PdfResult>, GetBookIssuedReportQueryHandler>();
```

I had to explicitly register the IRequestHandler with the Response

Comment: In which project within your solution is your `Program` class and in which project are your handlers? Within the `.AddMediatR()` method you have to pick the correct assembly.

Comment: Why not try `services.AddMediatR(m => m.RegisterServicesFromAssemblies(typeof(Program).Assembly), typeof(GetAllReportingQuery).Assembly);` instead? If that works without all of your manual registration, then clearly `GetAllReportingQuery` and its handler are in a different assembly.